# Obsolete methods on the stack error when doing hot code replacement (HCR) in java

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

I'm just running my java code in the main function. 
When I do the minor change in the method (`E.g commenting any of the system.out.println() statement`) and save it,
I immediately get an error message which says **Obsolete methods on the stack**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();

        /* This is how elements should be added to the array list */
        obj.add("Ajeet");
        obj.add("Harry");
        obj.add("Chaitanya");
        obj.add("Steve");
        obj.add("Anuj");

        /* Displaying array list elements */
        System.out.println("Currently the array list has following element:" + obj);

        /* Add element at the given index */
        obj.add(0, "Rahul");
        obj.add(1, "Justin");

        /* Remove elements from array list like this */
        obj.remove("Chaitanya");
        obj.remove("Harry");

        System.out.println("Current array is:" + obj);

        /* Remove element from the given index */
        obj.remove(1);

        System.out.println("Current array list i:" + obj);
    }
```

I have tried all the possible solutions in the below link. But still I'm facing this issue.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389221/eclipse-ide-debugging-code-not-reflects-new-changes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509214/in-eclipse-the-changes-of-my-source-code-have-no-effect
```

And `Project > Build Automatically` option is selected. I verified that.

I have used this debugging feature already in my previous projects but never faced this kind of issue. It will help my development effort faster.
And I'm not sure, why I'm getting this error now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance.

Eclipse Version - 4.7 & 4.5.2

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are doing hot code replace. (due to the build automatically option)

Another possibility is background building was happening so you launched before the build was complete. 
There is a preference to control this - see Preferences

Run/Debug > Wait for ongoing build to complete before launching.

Comment: This option is selected in preferences Run/Debug. (Always radio button is selected)